# When is it the optimal time to add flavoring?

Tags: bottling, flavor, secondary

I purchased a bottle of raspberry flavoring from a home brew store for a Lambic brew that is still in secondary. I don't believe the flavoring has any fermentables in it.

Should this flavoring be added to the secondary?

Or should I add it at bottling?

Answer (score 7):

Add it at bottling or kegging. The flavoring does not need to sit for a prolonged period if you do not add too much so adding it to the secondary would be redundant. The time in the bottles to carbonate should be plenty of time to get what you are looking for.

A tip for the amount to add:
Take a 1/2 pint and drop some of the flavoring in and taste, add a little more etc... until you are happy with the flavor then multiply out how many drops/weight to add for your batch volume.

Hope this helps,
Cheers.

Comment: nice answer. The advantage of doing it at packaging time is that the aromas are contained, and aroma is a major component of any flavoring. When adding the flavoring to the half pint, you of course need an accurate way to measure the quantity. A milliliter pipette can be useful for this.

Comment: @LastBoltonBrewery This cleared things up for me, Thanks.

Comment: @mdma I guess I will have to visit a hobby chemistry shop and get one.

Comment: you can also get them on online auction sites along with a pipette pump to draw the liquid.